# dynamic date change for chartkick from datetimepick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker, chartkick

I have the following code:

organization.html.erb

```
<div class="phonechart">
  <h3>Phone</h3>
  <%= line_chart @organization.statistics.with_kind(:phone).group_by_day(:created_at, range: Time.new(2016)..Time.new(2017)).count %>
</div>
```

and

organization.js

```
    function init_statistics_features() {

  $('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker({
  }).on('dp.change', function(e){

  });

  $('#enddate').datetimepicker({
  }).on('dp.change', function(e){});

}
```

how I can dynamic change date with datetimeficker?

Comment: You want to change the date that gets rendered in organization.html.erb when somebody changes a date?